# Wordpress plugin not styled?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a calendar plugin I wish to use, I tested it first on the WP '17 default theme and it displays just fine. I have my own custom theme I'm building using w3.css, very basic stuff.

I created a display area for widgets using

```
<?php
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Home right sidebar',
        'id'            => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");

?>
```

And put the following in an appropriate div within my index.php:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
```

As far as I can tell, when my "theme" outputs the widget there is no stylesheet attached to it. It's a calendar widget and displays the entire list of days of the month in a long list, rather than an enclosed area.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: pls provide a screenshot, however your current theme is not styled for that calendar plugin. You may need to copy some line of code from default theme for it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Eumge I've tried placing it in several different divs with more or less the same results each time. @Jared Chu, I didn't realize themes were necessarily styled around plugins, what kind of changes can I make to make it compatible? It seems to me that beyond sizing there isn't much more I can do.

Comment: Have you tried to put calendar to other position? Maybe it has conflict with sidebar css

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I hadn't called the footer which is apparently where the function hooks to. Now it's working as expected.

```
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

(Placed just before `</body>` in the index file.)

I also ended up using the following to call it:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="primary-sidebar" class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```